Variable type is dictating if a loop is infinite or not but I do not think it should, at least in this case
I am very new to programming, currently learning c language. Today I was doing some experiments with while loop and then stumbled upon this problem. I have noticed that I can get infinite number of W's by typing this code:
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double d;
    while(d)
    {
        printf("W");
    }
    return 0;
}

Infinite number of W's
However, if I change the variable type from double to int, float or char, I do not get any W whatsoever.
No W
To be honest, I do not even know why the given code yields infinite number of W's. I mean I have some general knowledge like if I type d == d between the 1st brackets of while loop [i.e. while(d == d)], I will get countless W's, regerdless of variable type. But I do not know how the given code yields the same result but does not work if the variable type is changed. I have tried looking for an answer on the internet but have not found anything useful. Can anyone please explain to me how the given code is functioning and why changing the variable type is impacting the outcome? Thanks in advance.

If your compiler isn't warning you about uninitialized variables, turn up the warnings till it does. (-Wall -Wextra is a good start for gcc and clang)

d is uninitialized. Reading it is undefined behavior.

auto variables like d will have an indeterminate value unless explicitly initialized.  It may be zero, it may be non-zero, it may be an invalid value for the type.
